# How to calculate facebox position based on image zoom changes in swiperjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I want to re-calculate the facebox positions based on zoom level in [Swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events)

Here is what i'm facing :

[image]

Here is what i have tried :  [Codepen](https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/vYPWxPG)

```js
function getTranslate3dPoints(){
              let transformStr = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-active .swiper-zoom-container').style.transform;
            let reg =  /^translate3d\(\s*(-?\d{0,4}(.?\d{0,4})?)px,\s*(-?\d{0,4}(.?\d{0,4})?)px\s*,\s*(-?\d{0,4}(.?\d{0,4})?)px\)$/;
          let match = transformStr.match(reg);

           console.log(`HeightY:`,Number(match[1]), 'WidthX:',match[3], 'Z:',match[5]);

  return {translateX: Number(match[1]) , translateY:Number(match[3]), translateZ:Number(match[5])};
}


var myPlugin = {
      name: 'debugger',
      params: {
        debugger: false,
      },
      on: {
        init: function () {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('init');
        },
        click: function (e) {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('click');
        },
        tap: function (e) {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('tap');
        },
        doubleTap: function (e) {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('doubleTap');
        },
        sliderMove: function (e) {
          //if (!this.params.debugger) return;
         // console.log('sliderMove');
         try{
          console.log('sliderMove Translate3d points:',getTranslate3dPoints());
         }catch(e){console.log(e)}
        },
        slideChange: function () {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('slideChange', this.previousIndex, '->', this.activeIndex);
        },
        slideChangeTransitionStart: function () {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('slideChangeTransitionStart');
        },
        slideChangeTransitionEnd: function () {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('slideChangeTransitionEnd');
        },
        transitionStart: function () {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('transitionStart');
        },
        transitionEnd: function (event) {
          //if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('transitionEnd',event);
        },
        fromEdge: function () {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('fromEdge');
        },
        reachBeginning: function () {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('reachBeginning');
        },
        reachEnd: function () {
          if (!this.params.debugger) return;
          console.log('reachEnd');
        },
        zoomChange: function(scale){
            console.log('Zoom Scale :',scale);
            console.log('Translate3d points:',getTranslate3dPoints());
        },
      },
    };
                </script>

                <script>
                    // Install Plugin To Swiper
    Swiper.use(myPlugin);

    // Init Swiper
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: true,
      loop: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      // Enable debugger
    });
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-zoom-container {
  touch-action: none;
}

.swiper-wrapper{
  position:relative;
}

.facebox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    height: 288px;
    width: 174px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    top: 22px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.5/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slider main container -->

    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="facebox"></div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
                    <img src="https://statics.boyner.com.tr/mnresize/1000/-/productimages/5002394556_467_05_900_1254.jpg">
        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
                        <img src="https://statics.boyner.com.tr/mnresize/1000/-/productimages/5002394556_467_05_900_1254.jpg">
        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
                            <img src="https://statics.boyner.com.tr/mnresize/1000/-/productimages/5002394556_467_05_900_1254.jpg">
        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Add Pagination -->
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <!-- Add Navigation -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                </div>
```

Please check codepen link for better view and manageability  **codepen:**  https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/vYPWxPG

My intention is to fix facebox when zoomlevel changes   but i'm not understanding how to calculate facebox with zoomlevel  as they are using

`transform : scale(1.3)` with changing scale values like 1,1.*,2,2.* etc , even for partial slide.

I have added a helper function `getTranslate3dPoints()` to get `translate3d`  points.

Still not finding correct solution !!

Comment: Please help me with your solution.

Comment: Not sure if there is an easy way to do this. The plugin methods only allow you to access the scale _factor_, as far as I can see - but depending on _where_ in the image you clicked to trigger the zoom, the zoom container element also gets a `translate3d` applied, with dynamically calculated values - and I don't see any method to query those. You would not only have to scale your facebox element, you would also need to _move_ it, and for that you'd need to know by how much the zoomed image container was translated.

Comment: @CBroe, how to include  `translate3d`  into moving box calculation any formula or approach would be very helpful for me , thanks in advance .

Comment: Can tell you at a glance, this will likely need some more in-depth analysis of the math going on in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we can put the facebox inside the each slider, this is how i'll do it. First, I add relative position to the zoom container:

```
.zoom-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Then I add the facebox and its container inside the zoom container:

```
...
      <div class="swiper-zoom-container zoom-container">
        <div class="facebox-container">
          <div class="facebox"></div>
        </div>
...
```

and make that facebox-container 100% in height and width:

```
...
.facebox-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}
...
```

Then add zoom listener to update the facebox-container scale (like how the image scale is changed):

```
...
    zoomChange: function (scale) {
      [...document.querySelectorAll(".facebox-container")].forEach((el) => {
        el.style.transform = `translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(${scale})`;
      });
    }
...
```

And that's it. Here is the forked pen: https://codepen.io/damzaky/pen/LYadqZM

Comment: Genius .........!!